# What are the best practices (patterns) to handle entity managers and transactions in SE environment?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Considering a Java SE app using JPA2 (RESOURCE_LOCAL), which would be the best way to manage my entity managers and transactions? I'd like to ensure transactions commits and rollbacks and avoid resource leaks by forgetting to call entityManager.close().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using spring framework it will make transaction handling transparent e.g. using annotations such as @Transaction, and you can simply inject EntityManager in any bean.

Comment: Is there any other alternatives rather than Spring Framework?